# Drawing square inside another square using angularjs and canvas tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AtcW0QHPa54WKIVXUOE6?p=preview) where i am trying to make a multiple square shapes using angularjs. I am using `<canvas>` tags in the html page.

I have a function `calc()` in which i am reducing the values of height and width by half an every iteration. The goal is to draw a series of squares where every next square is drawn within the previous one. Each child square had to be half the height and width of its parent and both horizontally and vertically centered.

I am not sure how to proceed in the code to draw the remaining squares in a loop

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this? (could be more efficient but I tried to keep your original structure)

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('keycount', []);
    app.controller('keycountcontroller', function($scope, $log, $http) {
      $scope.width = 500;
      $scope.height = 500;

      $scope.calc = function() {
        var x = $scope.width;
        var y = $scope.height;
        var parent = $('#myCanvas');
        while (x > 1) {
          x = x / 2;
          y = y / 2;
          var child = $(parent).clone(false)[0];
          $(child).css('width', x);
          $(child).css('height', y);
          $(child).css('position', 'relative');
          $(child).css('top', y/2);
          $(child).css('left', x/2);
          $(parent).append(child);
          parent = child;
          //alert(x);
        }
      }

      $scope.calc();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="keycountcontroller">
  <div id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #000000; width:{{width}}px; height:{{height}}px;"></div>
</body>
```

First I thought using a directive will make it better, Definitely more impressive, but not more efficient. So instead, here's a more compact version:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('keycount', []);
    app.controller('keycountcontroller', function($scope, $timeout) {
      $scope.width = 300;
      $scope.height = 300;

      $scope.calc = function() {
        var x = $scope.width;
        var y = $scope.height;
        var parent = $('#myCanvas');
        while (x > 1) {
          var child = $(parent).clone(false).css({ width: x = x / 2, height: y = y / 2, position: 'relative', top: x/2, left: y/2 });
          $(parent).append(child);
          parent = child;
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="keycountcontroller" ng-init="calc()">
  <div id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #000000; width:{{width}}px; height:{{height}}px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: i would like to know the more efficient way that you described :)